# html css and javascript - How can I prevent my car from going out of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, arrow-keys

I'm learning front-end at the moment and i'm trying to do a project for college but i'm stuck right now. When I press left arrow key my car goes off the screen and when i press right arrow key for some seconds a white infinite "div/something" shows up. I'm asking for help, i'm new at this and maybe some parts of the code might not make sense. There is any way to stop the arrow key press when the car is less than x pixels or something like that? I'm desesperate :(

[CODEPEN LINK](https://codepen.io/Leonardo06/project/editor/DnrKrO)

```js
function leftArrowPressed() {
    var car = document.getElementById("car_image");
    var right_wheel = document.getElementById("right_wheel");
    var left_wheel = document.getElementById("left_wheel");
    car.style.left = parseInt(car.style.left) - 50 + 'px';
    right_wheel.style.left = parseInt(right_wheel.style.left) - 50 + 'px';
    left_wheel.style.left = parseInt(left_wheel.style.left) - 50 + 'px';
    right_wheel.style.animation = 'rotation 2s infinite linear';
    left_wheel.style.animation = 'rotation 2s infinite linear';

    }

    function rightArrowPressed() {
    var car = document.getElementById("car_image");
    var right_wheel = document.getElementById("right_wheel");
    var left_wheel = document.getElementById("left_wheel");
    car.style.left = parseInt(car.style.left) + 50 + 'px';
    right_wheel.style.left = parseInt(right_wheel.style.left) + 50 + 'px';
    left_wheel.style.left = parseInt(left_wheel.style.left) + 50 + 'px';
    right_wheel.style.animation = 'rotation 2s infinite linear';
    left_wheel.style.animation = 'rotation 2s infinite linear';
    }


    function moveSelection(evt) {
        switch (evt.keyCode) {
            case 37:
            leftArrowPressed();
            break;
            case 39:
            rightArrowPressed();
            break;
            }
        };


{
  
  window.addEventListener('keydown', moveSelection);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.bg_image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bg_image img {
  width: 300vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.right-wheel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.left-wheel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  /*animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;*/
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Smart City</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
  </head>

  <body onload="docReady()" onkeydown="" onkeyup="">

    <div class="bg_image">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/L8gM86vB/teste.png" alt="">
    </div>
    
   <div class="car">
    <img id="car_image" src="https://i.postimg.cc/D0QPgs2d/Carro.png" style="position:absolute;left:30; bottom:0;">
    <img id="right_wheel" class="right-wheel" src="https://i.postimg.cc/RVDBmn1Z/roda-direita.png" style="position:absolute;left:61; bottom:5;">
    <img id="left_wheel" class="left-wheel" src="https://i.postimg.cc/RVDBmn1Z/roda-direita.png" style="position:absolute;left:264; bottom:5;">
    </div>

<script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: you have to get the bg_image div's width. 
you can get car possition also using javascript. 

so you can check car posission agaist div's width

Comment: Please could you check your snippet as it's trying to call a function docReady which isn't defined (same problem with the codepen) - and if I put in a dummy such function, an alert so it's got time to load, it shows only one wheel and that is in the wrong place in the snippet.

Comment: Try to access the codepen link: https://codepen.io/Leonardo06/project/editor/DnrKrO

I can't changed it here i don't know why

Comment: I already have the bg_image width, the car position and the screen width, how can i check de car position against screen width or image width?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `if(carPos.left >= maxScreenWidth) return;` as first validation inside arrowPressed for both should work.

**Get position of element**

```js
// Vanilla
var pos = car.getBoundingClientRect();

var carPos = {
  top: pos.top + window.pageYOffset,
  left: pos.left + window.pageXOffset
};

// jQuery
$('.car').position();
```

Comment: How do I get the car's position? I tried but the car just doesn't move anymore

Comment: @LeonardoRafael I added how to get position of the car.

Comment: I did that but the car does not move, i don't know what i'm doing wrong, i copy pasted your code, when i paste the `if(carPos.left >= maxScreenWidth) return;` the car just stops

Comment: I get the following error:

`script.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'left')
    at leftArrowPressed (script.js:11)
    at moveSelection (script.js:62)`